# Serving static files during development without relying on django.contrib.staticfiles

Tags: django

I'm trying to keep my front and back ends completely separate. Front end is a template developed in node-land with (I hope) minimal or no context involvement, back-end is a set of `TemplateViews` and an API.

I'm building my frontend to my `frontend` directory, so that's easy enough, I just set in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "DIRS": ["frontend/"]
    ...
```

I'm running into difficulties when these templates reference assets like:

```
<link rel="assets/css/foobar.css" />
```

`foobar.css` is present at the relevant location, but the dev server doesn't know to look there. Obviously in production the proxy server will be serving these files directly, but can I get the django dev server to do that while I'm developing? I really want to avoid prefixing with `{{ STATIC_URL }}` and other template tags that couple the back end to the templates.

Comment: Presumably you have the `staticfiles` app installed and your static files are specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your `settings.py`? If so, the Django dev server should automatically serve these when `DEBUG=True`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: Have a separate dev settings file that overrides:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/assets/')
STATIC_URL = 'assets/'
```

Now the dev server will be able to look in the correct location without relying on `{% static %}` tags.